# Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <testapp@model:testroute::ember1700:1> while in state root.loaded.updated.invalid

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a *route* named '*testroute*' (localhost:8080/testroute).

It has one record. I tried to edit it (localhost:8080/testroute/edit/1). I gave new values and submitted. The values got failed to cross server side validation and ***error message*** was thrown with the *status code **422***.

Then I decided not to edit it anymore. From here itself I went another route named '*nextroute*' (localhost:8080/nextroute).

Now, again I tried to go to 'testroute' (localhost:8080/testroute). It didnot go and in console I got error as "Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on  while in state root.loaded.updated.invalid."

What I used to make ajax call with the edited values is

```
this.get('model').save().then(function(response){
      console.log('response',response);
      //code
},function(error){
      console.log('error',error);
      //code
});
```

When I refresh the page I can go to 'testroute' (localhost:8080/testroute). But after this error come I can't open.

The record was in modified state in ember-date (I saw it in ember inspector). When I refresh it only it goes to clean state.

Comment: what is the response of your error? Is your server running on local host aswell?

Comment: Yeah.. Server was running only. When i saw in network, response was got correct only for (localhost:8080/testroute). But the page was not displayed. It was still on the page (localhost:8080/nextroute). In console this error was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fom what I can tell, your server couldn't process your post/patch request and returned an error. Therefore, your model is in an invalid state. What you should do, is, once the error is returned, to [rollback](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes) your model:

```
var model = this.get('model')
model.save().then(function(response){
      console.log('response',response);
      //code
},function(error){
      console.log('error',error);
      model.rollbackAttributes();
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to keep the model in its state until you leave the page, you should make use of the `willTransition` event of your route, e.g.:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if (this.controller.get('model.errors')) {
          Ember.Logger.debug('model will be reverted');
          this.controller.get('model').rollbackAttributes()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Remi. This will solve my problem. But if we rollback the model, the error message can not be shown since the error is also cleared when doing rollback. The error message is received as model.errors.